# Entity Properties from another joined table/view in Doctrine2

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm

I'm currently stuck with the following SQL schema (I don't own the DB unfortunately and cannot change it either)

```
+----------------------------------------+
|          TABLE "products"              |
+----------------------------------------+
| Column             |  Type             |
+----------------------------------------+
| id                 | integer           |
| price              | float             |
| purchased          | datetime          |
+----------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------+
|          VIEW "product_names"          |
+----------------------------------------+
| Column             |  Type             |
+----------------------------------------+
| product_id (FK)    | integer           |
| name               | varchar           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Now since i'm using Doctrine2.1 on this project i'm wondering if it's possible to define a `Product` Entity that fetches it's name from the `product_names` VIEW and the rest of the data from the `products` TABLE?

Basically I want an entity that executes the following query when fetching all products:

```
SELECT p.id, p.price, p.purchased, n.name 
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_names n
ON p.id = n.product_id
```

I looked into OneToOne associations but that doesn't cut it because that defines the association between two Entities, not the Entity's properties.

Comment: Use a OneToOne association with cascade and have accessor routines for the parent automatically handle the sub-entity creation/updating.

Comment: Ah, it's a VIEW - how is the name edited then?  If you just want it read only, as above.

Comment: The name indeed is read-only, i'll check the OneToOne with Cascade option, so basically the idea is that I create a separate Entity called `ProductName` only for this purpose?

Comment: OK, i've managed to solve it by defining a unidirectional OneToOne relation, works like a charm, write up an answer and i'll accept it.  Problem is now that when running the schema-tool a table will be created for this `ProductName` entity even though a view with that exact name already exists. I've started a separate question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563005/ignore-a-doctrine2-entity-when-running-schema-manager-update