# Ignore a Doctrine2 Entity when running schema-manager update

Tags: doctrine-orm

I've got a Doctrine Entity defined that maps to a View in my database. All works fine, the Entity relations work fine as expected.

Problem now is that when running `orm:schema-manager:update` on the CLI a table gets created for this entity which is something I want to prevent. There already is a view for this Entity, no need to create a table for it.

Can I annotate the Entity so that a table won't be created while still keeping access to all Entity related functionality (associations, ...)?

Comment: Looks like this question popped up on the Doctrine mailinglist some time ago but remained unanswered. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/qrlvGx7HxdQ

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eventually it was fairly simple, I just had to subclass the `\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand` into my own CLI Command. In that subclass filter the `$metadatas` array that's being passed to `executeSchemaCommand()` and then pass it on to the parent function.

Just attach this new subclassed command to the ConsoleApplication you are using in your doctrine cli script and done!

Below is the extended command, in production you'll probably want to fetch the `$ignoredEntities` property from you config or something, this should put you on the way.

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

class My_Doctrine_Tools_UpdateCommand extends UpdateCommand
{
    protected $name = 'orm:schema-tool:myupdate';

    protected $ignoredEntities = array(
        'Entity\Asset\Name'
    );

    protected function executeSchemaCommand(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, SchemaTool $schemaTool, array $metadatas, SymfonyStyle $ui)
    {
        /** @var $metadata \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata */
        $newMetadata = [];
        foreach ($metadatas as $metadata) {
            if (!in_array($metadata->getName(), $this->ignoredEntities)) {
                $newMetadata[] = $metadata;
            }
        }
        return parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $newMetadata, $ui);
    }
}
```

PS: credits go to Marco Pivetta for putting me on the right track. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/rwWXZ7faPsA

Comment: This solution prevent doing foreign key pointing to ignored entities.

Comment: Thanks sylvain, haven't bumped into that issue yet but it's good to know!

Comment: A good example to implement it in Symfony2 would be great, I've added that command to my CoreBundle commands and when I run it I get some error: The helper "em" is not defined. - I think i missed the part of adding the command to "the ConsoleApplication you are using in your doctrine cli script" - dont know how to do that in Symfony2.

Comment: You could do better by `return parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $newMetadatas);` instead.

Comment: I find the solution exclusively for my case, if i set in ,apping for my entity as mappedSuperClass it will be ignored for update toolbar/validate

Answer (score 16):

Based on the original alswer of ChrisR inspired in Marco Pivetta's post I'm adding here the solution if you're using Symfony2:

Looks like Symfony2 doesn't use the original Doctrine command at:
\Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand

Instead it uses the one in the bundle:
\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand

So basically that is the class that must be extended, ending up in having:

`src/Acme/CoreBundle/Command/DoctrineUpdateCommand.php`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Command;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle;

class DoctrineUpdateCommand extends UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand
{
    protected function executeSchemaCommand(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output, SchemaTool $schemaTool, array $metadatas, SymfonyStyle $ui): ?int
    {
        $ignoredEntities = [
            'App\Entity\EntityToIgnore',
        ];
        $metadatas = array_filter($metadatas, static function (ClassMetadata $classMetadata) use ($ignoredEntities) {
            return !in_array($classMetadata->getName(), $ignoredEntities, true);
        });
        return parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $metadatas, $ui);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do better by `return parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $newMetadatas);` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Quite old one but there is also worth nothing solution using `Doctrine2`: `postGenerateSchema` event listener - for me it's better than overriding
`Doctrine` classes:

```php
namespace App\Doctrine\Listener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Event\GenerateSchemaEventArgs;

/**
 * IgnoreTablesListener class
 */
class IgnoreTablesListener
{
    private $ignoredTables = [
        'table_name_to_ignore',
    ];

    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args)
    {
        $schema = $args->getSchema();
        $tableNames = $schema->getTableNames();
        foreach ($tableNames as $tableName) {
            if (in_array($tableName, $this->ignoredTables)) {
                // remove table from schema
                $schema->dropTable($tableName);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Also register listener:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    ignore_tables_listener:
        class: App\Doctrine\Listener\IgnoreTablesListener
        tags:
            - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postGenerateSchema }
```

No extra hooks is necessary.

Comment: Drawback here is that the schema gets generated and you drop a table afterwards, seems like a suboptimal solution to me because I would prefer the table not being created all together. The end result is the same though so for some people this might be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but only `Schema` instance is created (generated) - not executed. In this case `dropTable` means unset table from `Schema` instance. If you call: `d:s:u --dump-sql` you will receive generated schema SQL without ignored tables.

Comment: This solution is better if you don't have error in your schema. It allows foreign key pointing on ignored stuffs. But I need to ignore just because there is some specific error with many entities so I'd like to skip them. **PS : ** I meet your blog @KamilAdryjanek and you should remove the dependency calling of the entity manager. It givers circular reference error. Instead the `$args` arguments have already `getEntityManager` method.

Comment: All the solutions I have tried, but it generating entity files and also throwing an error "No identifier/primary key specified for Entity", it means its not skipping the entity. Please suggest otherwise

Comment: Is this still working? It seems it has no effect anymore... those tables are still included in migrations, even if the service is called, if I do a `dd($schema)` the table is not there

Answer (score 6):

In Doctrine 2.7.0 it was introduced the new `SchemaIgnoreClasses` entity manager config option that basically ignores the configured classes from any schema action.

To use it with Symfony we only need to add the `schema_ignore_classes` key in the Doctrine entity manager configuration like this:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # your dbal configuration
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
                schema_ignore_classes:
                    - Reference\To\My\Class
                    - Reference\To\My\OtherClass
```

Answer (score 0):

`$schema->getTableNames()` was not working (I don't know why).

So:

```php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\Proxy\UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Event\GenerateSchemaEventArgs;

class IgnoreTablesListener extends UpdateSchemaDoctrineCommand
{

    private $ignoredEntities = [
        'YourBundle\Entity\EntityYouWantToIgnore',
    ];

    /**
     * Remove ignored tables /entities from Schema
     *
     * @param GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args
     */
    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args)
    {
        $schema = $args->getSchema();
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();


        $ignoredTables = [];
        foreach ($this->ignoredEntities as $entityName) {
            $ignoredTables[] = $em->getClassMetadata($entityName)->getTableName();
        }


        foreach ($schema->getTables() as $table) {

            if (in_array($table->getName(), $ignoredTables, true)) {
                // remove table from schema
                $schema->dropTable($table->getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Register a service

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    ignore_tables_listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\IgnoreTablesListener
        tags:
            - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postGenerateSchema }
```

Worked fine! ;)

Answer (score -3):

If problem is only with producing errors in db_view, when calling doctrine:schema:update command, why not simplest way:

1. remove @ from @ORM\Entity annotation
2. execute doctrine:schema:update
3. add @ to ORM\Entity annotation

;-)

Comment: Very bad idea. How to proceed if you work on pre-prod or prod environment ? often, you can't access to the code.