# Doctrine 2 and MySQL: association mapping between a table and a view

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, model-associations, sql-view

I'm trying to create an association between 2 entites. The left one is a table representation. The right is a view representation.

I just succeeded at making this relation work, but I have problem when creating the schema with `php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create`.

Below is all the code needed to try it:

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `demo` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'demo 1'),
(2, 'demo 2'),
(3, 'demo 3'),
(4, 'demo 4');

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `demo_metadata` AS select `se`.`id` AS `demo_id`,12 AS `demo_count` from `demo` `se`;
```

Demo Table Entity

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="demo")
 */
class Demo {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", length=30)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="DemoMetadata")
     * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="demo_id")
     */
    private $metadata;

    public function getMetadata() {
        return $this->metadata;
    }
}
```

Demo View Entity

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="demo_metadata")
 */
class DemoMetadata {

    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $demo_id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
    private $demo_count;

    public function getDemoCount() {
        return $this->demo_count;
    }
}
```

Query and fetching data

```
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb
    ->select('d')
    ->from('Demo', 'd')
    ->leftJoin('d.metadata', 'dm')
    ->where('d.id = ?0')
    ->setParameter(0, 1);

$demo_object = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
var_dump($demo_object->getMetadata()->getDemoCount());

// display: int(12)
```

As we can see, the metadata property of the Demo Entity is populated with the data from the view. Everything works fine and as expected.

But with such a configuration, when running the cli command to drop the schema, and then recreate it, an error occurs because `demo_metadata` table already exist.

In the end, I'm not searching for a way to create automatically the view. I have SQL scripts that I can call to create the view. I'm wondering if there's a way to not trying to create the table for some entities?

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Tools\ToolsException]                                                                                                                                                                             
Schema-Tool failed with Error 'An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE demo_metadata (demo_id INT NOT NULL, demo_count INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(demo_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8 _unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':                                                                                                                                                                                   
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'demo_metadata' already exists' while executing DDL: CREATE TABLE demo_metadata (demo_id INT NOT NULL, demo_count INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(demo_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB
```

It's just a matter of convenience, because the views already exist and are not dropped with the cli drop command.

Is it that the only way to manage this is to:

1. drop schema (doctrine cli)
2. remove `demo_metadata` view
3. create schema (doctrine cli)
4. remove `demo_metadata` table
5. create `demo_metadata` view

Thanks

**Edit**

In the end, I used this code to filter the entities I needed:

```
<?php

class UpdateSchema extends \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\SchemaTool\UpdateCommand {

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function executeSchemaCommand(
        InputInterface $input, 
        OutputInterface $output, 
        SchemaTool $schemaTool, 
        array $metadatas) : int
    {
        $entities = array_filter($metadatas, function ($m) {
            return !$m->isReadOnly;
        });
        return parent::executeSchemaCommand($input, $output, $schemaTool, $entities);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>In addition to `create` and `drop` commands, there is also an `update` command. That's the one you should be using if the database already exists</s>

Wrong answer, see comments for correct

Comment: I tried with `update` as you proposed, but even if a view exists with the name `demo_metadata`, the update mechanism tries to create a new table `demo_metadata` and an error occurs. I'm forced to remove the view, make the update, remove the "wrong" table and recreate the view...

Comment: My bad, didn't read the question properly in hurry. This question is what you are asking about probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563005/ignore-a-doctrine2-entity-when-running-schema-manager-update

Comment: okay, thanks! I must admit I would have preferred a solution via annotations, like @Table(nogenerate=true), but the cli update override works perfectly! And it helps me to eventually ask my question from an better angle. Thanks