# doctrine:schema:update wants to create an already existing view in symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an existing view in my SQL database "view_account" which represents a account entity. This view is read only and has no primary_key field. Actually it has a primary key "id" but the field is not declared as primary key. I can also not change the table design, because its an automatic export from another application generating this tables (the automatic export is every week).

But thats not the problem cause doctrine don't care about "primary key" flag in the database until you don't update the schema.

But whenever i try to "doctrine:schema:update --force" doctrine wants to create this table. How can i ignore this view (or better the entity) from updating by doctrine? Marking the entity read_only with doctrine annotation is not working. Extending a own update-command will also not work, as i found out, it will not work since doctrine 2.4.7 to extend the doctrine-schema-update command (the update command method is ignored in any way).

Whats the best solution?

Edit:

I also tried to configure two entitymanager. One for the "internal" entities and for the "foreign" entities. Since all entities are linked to each other on some point, it is also not possible to have two separated manager don't knowing from each other entities.

Comment: a side note: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/564 . Plus it may worth try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25948910/1595977

Comment: Thanks Edwin, i updated my description. Thats some approach i already tried but does also not work.

Comment: To your last idea i found this: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/issues/728 ... that seems few days ago and will also not work anymore