# Symfony 5 - Doctrine with schema_filter not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony4, symfony5

I try to ignore two entities when I execute the command line `doctrine:schema:update --force` in my project who is writing like this :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 * @ORM\Table(name="view_tableau_de_bord")
 */
class ViewTableauDeBord
{
    //...
}
```

In my doctrine.yaml configuration file:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    default_connection: default

    connections:
        default:
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            driver: 'pdo_pgsql'
            server_version: '12'
            charset: utf8
            schema_filter: ~^(?!view_)~
        # ...
```

Doctrine keeps generating all entities while my views are in the `schema_filter`. Do you have an explanation about this ? It's my first time with this option in a project.

Configuration du projet:

- Symfony 5.4.14
- PHP 7.4.26
- doctrine:orm: 2.13.3
- doctrine/annotations: 1.13.3
- doctrine/doctrine-bundle: 2.7.0
- doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle: 3.2.2
- symfony/doctrine-bridge: 5.4.14
- doctrine/data-fixtures: 1.5.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## schema_filter

`schema_filter` is not made to "filter" entity but to filter db table from doctrine awareness.

**Here is an example :**
Assuming you manually create a table that is updated from a custom raw php cronjob called `view_booking_by_customer_per_year`, this table is not used by your code in your project but is used for data analysis.

This is a typical example where you do not want doctrine to generate a query like this each time you want to update your schema.

```
DROP TABLE view_booking_by_customer_per_year; // NO I DONT WANT THIS
```

So using `schema_filter` you can tell doctrine to ignore this table in his validation and update process.

Try to create a random table using raw sql and use `doctrine:schema:validate`.
It will show `database is not in sync` error.
Once you put it in schema_filter, the error won't occur anymore.

It work for `doctrine:migration:diff` and `doctrine:schema:update`

### schema_ignore_class

But if you want to avoid an entity to be generated inside the database there is this from the link in the answer of Ernesto:

```
 schema_ignore_classes:
   - Reference\To\My\Class
   - Reference\To\My\OtherClass
```

Only working since Doctrine 2.7 version.
You can find the complete example here : [Ignore a Doctrine2 Entity when running schema-manager update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563005/ignore-a-doctrine2-entity-when-running-schema-manager-update?noredirect=1&lq=1)

#### Use doctrine migration

I strongly advise you to use `doctrine:migration:diff` then `doctrine:migration:migrate` instead of `doctrine:schema:update` to perform change on database. It's ok for local dev, but when in production it is a very bad practice.

https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html

Comment: @nboulfroy re-updated answer with solution (i hope) this time

Answer (score 1):

An entity marked with the flag `readOnly=true` is not tracked for updates anymore but it is still possible to insert or delete rows, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.13/reference/annotations-reference.html#entity).

The `doctrine:schema:update` command will still take the table into account to update the schema.

In the answers to the question ["Ignore a Doctrine2 Entity when running schema-manager update"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563005/ignore-a-doctrine2-entity-when-running-schema-manager-update) there are 3 valid options to ignore the entity from schema update.

Comment: This solution is not working. Even if I remove "readOnly" parameter from "@ORM\Entity" annotation, the table is always generated.

Comment: @nboulfroy the "readonly" attribute allows the entity to not update when you do an object modification and then do a `persist` and `flush`. It doesn't influence the schema update with the `doctrine:schema:update` command.