# doctrine schema update wants to drop migration_verions table symfony

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

When I try to run `doctrine:schema:update --complete --dump-sql` on a Symfony dockerized application, the output is showing below:

```
ALTER TABLE offer DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_29D6873EC1EA42F3;
DROP TABLE doctrine_migration_versions;
```

I expect that the table migration_versions should not be deleted!
I am using `mariadb:10.9.4 mysql`

Answer (score 4):

#### Updated answer with the comment of @iloo

Add `schema_filter` to your doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(DATABASE_URL)%'
        schema_filter: "~^(?!doctrine_migration_versions$)~"
```

And try to launch the command without the --complete option

You can read better explanation on this on one of my old answer :
[Symfony 5 - Doctrine with schema_filter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74991256/symfony-5-doctrine-with-schema-filter-not-working/74992502#74992502)

Comment: removing the --complete options does not show that even without adding these lines but I'm confused why adding the --complete options shows doctrine wants to drop that table

Comment: That's new to me also, and when i dont use --complete option it says it is deprecated to not use it. Was not the case 2 month earlier.  I discovered it with your question. I did not have time to go deep in doctrine documentation. But yes, this is weird.
Anyway, as i always say : use doctrine migration to update database, not doctrine:schema function

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around: you make `schema_filter` to return everything else **except** for `doctrine_migration_versions`, i.e. `schema_filter: "~^(?!doctrine_migration_versions$)~"`.

Comment: @iloo You are correct, the schema_filter option works but the expression in the configuration above is wrong, your expression did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Hydde87 yes it would resolve the problem temporary but then generate an error when running migration telling table doe snot exists